# Add single row using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, animation

Here is the PHP code in brief I'm working on,

```
$feed_url = "JASON Feed URL";
$json = file_get_contents($feed_url);
$products = json_decode($json);

foreach($products as $product){
$id = $product->id;
$name = $product->name;
$link = $product->link;
}
$query = INSERT INTO TABLE(id,name,link) VALUES ($id,$name,$link);
$result = mysqli_query($query);
```

I'm able to pull list of all products. Now, I want to add "selective products" to my database.

for example, I want to show "Install" button bellow each product and as I hit "Install", the product details will add to my database and show "Pre-load animation image". (I don't want to use submit "form method" as it will refresh the search.)

I know this can be achieved using AJAX but I never learned AJAX :-( As I've to complete this project urgently no time to learn AJAX (definitely learn after finishing current work)

Somebody, please suggest basic function or steps to do this, I'll find more information on my own to complete it. A little help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't condone giving full answers but I know what it's like to be stuck :)

If you have the install button setup like this with a loading image underneath:

```
<a class="installButton" id="product1">Install</a>
<img src="images/loading.gif" id="loading" />
```

Where the id of a corresponds to the product id then you can make a jQuery function as follows:

```
$('.installButton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#loading").show();
    var productId = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "yourPhpScript.php",
        data: "productId="+productId,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            $("#loading").hide();
        }           
    )};
});
```

You would then modify your PHP script to take the product id from the `$_GET` superglobal and only insert that into the database:

```
// Here we get the product id and store it in a variable for use.
$product_id = $_GET['productId'];

$feed_url = "JASON Feed URL";
$json = file_get_contents($feed_url);
$products = json_decode($json);

foreach($products as $product){
    // Here we make sure that we only get the data of the corresponding product id.
    if( $product->id == $product_id ) {
        $id = $product->id;
        $name = $product->name;
        $link = $product->link;
    }
}

$query = INSERT INTO TABLE(id,name,link) VALUES ($id,$name,$link);
$result = mysqli_query($query);
```

Comment: gimg1 thanks for reply, I'm not getting product id from other pages, actually I'm browsing list of all available products via feed and choosing single or multiple product from the list and adding to Database.

Comment: So the products will be listed out on a page with all their corresponding details and you want an install button beside each to add them to a database?

Comment: yes, after pulling products details from feed, I want to choose which one to add and which not to add. I'll add "Install" button bellow each product, and as I hit install button, the only product will get add to database.